# Comparing two IEnumerable to detect changes

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, comparison, ienumerable

For my first post here, I have a question regarding IEnumerable comparison.
I have a bindable structure based on an enumeration logic. The content of the IEnumerable changes over time and I have to manually fire CollectionChanged events.

I have a very naive algorithm that allows me to detect simple changes between two states of the IEnumerable (simple add, simple remove, multiple add, multiple remove) but it's not very efficient and does not detect everything.

A quick example of what I need :

**State 1 of the IEnumerable :** A * B * C * D * E

**State 2 of the IEnumerable :** A * C * B * D * D1

For this example, I would have to detect

- One move operation : B changed index from 1 to 2
- One Add operation : D1 was inserted at index 4
- One remove operation : E was removed

Is there an algorithm to solve this problem as efficiently as possible ( O(nLog(n)) would be a good start) ?

Thanks !

Comment: has B moved from index 1 -> 2 or has C moved from 2 -> 1? or both?

Comment: If state 1 is `A B` and state 2 is `B A A`, have two items been added, or one added and one moved? If `A` moved, where did it move to?

Comment: @JamesB : B moved from index 1 -> 2 information should be enough !

Comment: If an item is removed from the list then all subsequent items have moved, right?

Comment: @Jon : A moved from index 0 -> 1. Another A was added.

Comment: @Jodrell : Actually no, I just have to detect a remove operation.

Comment: Should the items be compared by reference or value?

Comment: This should be an option actually, I should be able to support both

Comment: Can items move by more than one index? If more than one match for a move is found, which wins? The closest?

Comment: There seem far too many ambiguous situations. Given ABCDEFG -> AEFBCEFDG, The EF has moved, but has it moved to the first EF or the second?

Comment: Well it does not really matter. First match will be considered correct. The main idea is that I have an IEnumerable that will changes over time : I already have a notification mechanism that alerts me that the state changed. I have the old and new state and I want to fire CollectionChanged events with the correct NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs to notify the UI of what has changed for it to be updated correctly.

Comment: Given the case ABCDEFG -> AEFBCEFDG, it does not matter if I consider that it has been moved to the first or second, I just have to generate the correct notification for one "move" and one "add".

Comment: O(n*log(n)) seems unlikely on a non-sorted collection but I might be wrong. Also: given ABCDE -> ABCDEABCDE what is the expected result ?

Comment: It should be an "Add" notification with "ABCDE" as new items.

Comment: Ok, now it gets harder: in which position ? 0 or 5 ? who's who ? :D @JamesB answer looks good by the way

Comment: Well 0 or 5 does not matter. Considereing the objects are equals, result will be the same. I'm currently checking his answer, it looks good indeed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is uncompiled, untested and atleast partially psuedo code.

Given a single move detection being sufficient Items can only move forward, moving backwards will be the result of another item being move or removed

e.g. 
State 1 of the IEnumerable : A * B * C * D * E

State 2 of the IEnumerable : A * D * B * C * D1

Result in both B and C moving forward.

```
enum1pos = -1;
enum2pos = 0;
  Value2 = enum2.Next()
  enum2pos++;
List<int> SkipList = new SkipList();
while(enum1 has values left)
{
  Value1 = enum1.Next()
  enum1pos++;
  //Skip over moved items.
  while (SkipList.Count > 0 && SkipList[0] == enum2.Position)
  {
    Value2 = enum2.Next()
    enum2pos++;
  }
  if (Value1 == Value2)
    Value2 = enum2.Next()
    enum2pos++;
    continue;

  int temp = enum2pos;
  while(Value1 !=Value and enum2 has more values)
  {
    Value2 = enum2.Next();
    enum2pos++;
  }
  if(Value1 != Value2)
    ItemDeleted(Value1);
  else
  {
    ItemMoved(Value1, enum2pos);
    SkipList.Add(enum2pos);
  }
  //This is expensive for IEnumerable!
  enum2.First();
  loop temp times
    enum2.Next();
  //if 
}
while (enum2 has values left)
{
  while (SkipList.Count > 0 && SkipList[0] == enum2.Position)
  {
    Value2 = enum2.Next()
    enum2pos++;
  }
  if (enum2 has values left)
  Added(Value2, enum2pos)
}
```

Result: 
Compare A and A
Next
Compare B and D
Find B
B Moved -> 2
Add 2 to Skip List
Reset Enum2
Compare C and D
Find C
C Moved -> 3
Add 3 to Skip List
Reset Enum2
Next
Compare D and D
Next
Skip(2)
Skip(3)
Compare E and D1
Find E
Removed(E)
Next
End of Enum1
Added(D1,4)

I think there's a saving somewhere if enum2pos gets too far behind to see if it's been removed and if it hasn't add a skip to for it's original position in enum1, this would help with with enum2's position being reset all of the time.

Comment: Seems like a good option. O(n) at best, O(n*m) at worst. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Sisyphe, Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept an answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Sure, I'll try an implementation by Monday ! Actually most of the IEnumerable operations will be single Add, single Remove, or single Move. In these cases, this algorithm should be very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer using Linq, here is a simple solution based on your example.. Sorry but not sure of the performance..

```
var a = new List<string>{"A","B","C","D","E"};
var b = new List<string>{"A","C","B","D","D1"};

var removed = a.Except(b);
var moved = a.Where(x => b[a.IndexOf(x)] != x && !removed.Contains(x));
List<string> newlyInserted = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in removed)
{
    //Newly inserted into the list - D1
    newlyInserted.Add(b[a.IndexOf(item)]);
    //Index of D1 if required
    var indexOfNewlyAddedItem = a.IndexOf(item);
}
```

or simply

```
var newlyAdded = b.Except(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually this way of doing thing is at least quadratic, so it won't solve my issue :( Moreover, as I have to fire CollectionChanged events, I need the list of added/removed objects along with their indexes so using Except is not enough. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Not extending this as I don't know the entirety of your requirement, but you can simply use IndexOf() to find the indices of the identified items. Hope you will find a better answer for your problem.

Comment: Move detection LINQ query - fantastic! Thank you!